# Ansible set variable value depending on facts

Tags: ansible

I want to make an ansible task that will copy some file to the client.
Which file will be copied is decided by the client architecture (x86 or i386).
What is the best way to do such thing without code duplication?

I mean, it will be awesome if I could use just one task like:

```
name: copy file
copy: src={{ src }} dest={{ dest }}
```

With some manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Jinja2 if expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if-expression) for that:

```
vars:
  src: "{{ 'file_amd64.tar.gz' if ansible_architecture == 'x86_64' else 'file_i386.tar.gz' }}"
tasks:
  - name: copy file
    copy: src={{ src }} dest={{ dest }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to come up with the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the system specific settings in vars files which are named after the architecture.

In your role you'd have a file `x86.yml` with contents:

```
...

copySrc: fileA
copyDest: /some/path/A

---
```

And the same for `i386.yml`:

```
...

copySrc: fileB
copyDest: /some/path/B

---
```

Then use the system fact `ansible_architecture` to include the correct file:

```
- include_vars: "{{ ansible_architecture }}.yml"

- name: Copy file
  copy:
    src={{ copySrc }}
    dest={{ copyDest }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to come up with the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:
I have 2 directories in `files` directory: `x86_64` and `i386`.
Each contains `my_file` (with relevant content).

My role contains this task:

```
name: copy file
copy: src={{ ansible_architecture }}/my_file dest={{ dest }}
```